What can we say about the convexity of $GL^{+}(n,\mathbb{R})$?
My question seems like a very simple one, yet I am having trouble finding a definitive answer. I know that the set of invertible (real) matrices, $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is open, yet disconnected, with two separate connected components: matrices with positive determinants, and matrices with negative determinants. We call the former component $GL^{+}(n,\mathbb{R})$.
I want to know if this set is convex. In other words, if $A,B \in GL^{+}(n,\mathbb{R})$, and if $L(t)$ is the linear homotopy between them, $L(t) = (1-t)A + tB$, then convexity means that $\det(L(t)) > 0$ for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and all choices of $A$ and $B$.
Some of the stuff I have found online seemed to indicate that this set is not convex, but I am struggling to find a counterexample — at least when looking at $2\times2$ matrices. Some of the stuff I've seen has also mentioned something about convex cones, but I was having trouble following if that was directly relevant to the answer I'm looking for.
Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.
EDIT: It was pointed out that I was missing the simple counterexample between  $I_2$ and $-I_2$. So what are we able to say then? How does the convex cone come into play here?

$\frac{I_2+(-I_2)}{2}=0$.

But $-I_2$ is not in $GL^{+}$.

Why not? It has determinant $1$.

Oh... duh! I don't know what I was thinking. So then what can we say about the set? Is the convex cone idea relevant here at all?

You can say it is path connected.

@ArinChaudhuri Is there some sort of all-purpose algorithm that can give you the explicit path, given the two matrices you wish to connect?

@user1551 One thing is bugging me though. You example definitely shows that $GL^{+}$ is not convex, but it fails by transitioning through a matrix with determinant zero. Are there counterexamples where the transition gives a negative determinant? Because if it can't then that's interesting, and would seem to paint a more nuanced problem of convexity.

Sure. Join $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} -3&0\0&-2\end{bmatrix}$.

You can easily establish a method for determining those matrices $A \in GL^+(n, \mathbb{R})$ that can be connected to the identity by a straight line. For such matrices, you only need to write:
$$
tA + (1-t)I = -t\bigg( \bigg(1-\frac{1}{t}\bigg)I - A \bigg),
$$
and from this:
$$
\det(tA + (1-t)I) = (-t)^n \det\bigg(\bigg(1-\frac{1}{t}\bigg)I - A\bigg) = (-t)^n P_A\bigg(1-\frac{1}{t}\bigg),
$$
where $P_A$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of $A$.
Notice that in the above expression, $1 - \frac{1}{t}$ takes all non-positive values when $t$ ranges over $(0, 1]$. From this, it follows that a necessary and sufficient condition is that $P_A$ does not have a root on the non-positive real axis (thus, if all roots are complex, this is certainly possible).
In the general case, there exists a way to obtain a path from $A$ to $I$, as follows: $A$ always has an invariant subspace, with dimension 1 or 2. Thus, there exists a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in which the linear operator associated with $A$ has the matrix representation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
M_1 & M_2 \\
0 & M_3
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $M_1$ is a square matrix of dimension 1 or 2 (if dimension 1 is possible, always choose that) and has a positive determinant. Using this form, you can construct a trivial path from $A$ to a matrix with the following representation in the same basis:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
M_1 & 0 \\
0 & M_3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
For $M_1$, it is easy to construct a path to the identity. If $M_1$ has dimension 2, then $M_2$ must have complex eigenvalues (by the way $M_2$ was selected), and you can apply the first method described above to obtain a path to the identity. If the dimension is 1, the path is trivial.
So, you can handle $M_3$ inductively.
